# How can I set a form to be valid in Angular 7

Tags: angular, forms

How can I set form to be valid in Angular 7? The select inside reactive form is valid, all controls are valid, but the form is invalid. I have no idea. What's the reason for that behavior?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about since I don't see your code. Can you please share it?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well validation means, you have to pass correct values.
There will be no use of validators if you bypass them.

**However you can try this API but it wont remove the validators :**

```
this.<your_form_name>.controls['control_name'].setErrors({'incorrect': false});
```

or you can loop all over the controls and set all controls error as false.

Comment: I checked all the controls inside. all are valid. but form remained in valid. surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason:
      // self[FormName].setValidators(selectOneValidator);
      // self[FormName].updateValueAndValidity();
 I used to do this after I set the default value in the drop down list. this was causing the issue.

removed it. it started working.